# Bot Framework Facebook Webhook Event Mapping

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to identify what the bot framework maps events to `ActivityTypes`.  I can't find anything in the documentation and I can't seem to identify in the SDK code where this mapping is happening in order to figure it out.  Using v4 Bot Framework and C#.

What would these be mapped too?

- messages
- messaging_postbacks
- messaging_optins
- message_deliveries
- messaging_referrals
- standby
- messaging_handovers

Comment: Are you using c# or Node SDK and is this v3 or v4?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question to include the missing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a map of webhook events to bot activity types. You may be able to create some sort of middleware that is able to capture 'message_deliveries' and 'standby'. But, at this time, they are not captured in any way that they can be acted on.

- messages -> ActivityTypes.Message
- messaging_postbacks -> ActivityTypes.Message
- messaging_optins -> ActivityTypes.Message
- message_deliveries -> Data is sent via the 'delivery' channel which is not captured by the bot
- messaging_referrals  -> ActivityTypes.Message
- standby -> Data is sent via the 'standby' channel which is not captured by the bot
- messaging_handovers -> ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate

Per Facebook's [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/standby), any message and delivery events sent via standby can be retrieved via message history.

Hope of help!